# creation of json with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've created a application for converting the HTML table to JSON. the code works fine, but say for example if the `td` or `th` contains inner components such as span or other child elements , we have to iterate within that to get the real text, in my application I've wrote for getting values if there is one span components, but in other situation if there is more than one components how can we get the real values inside the td and th of table, here we are considering only text values

Comment: try `.text()` instead of `.htm()` when getting the values from your `<td>`

Comment: @RobSedgwick i did'nt get u...in my code i've used `.text()` and have'nt used `.htm()`

Comment: provided an example. Morepaolo has also provide a link to the Jquery .text() method - http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: This `if (td.innerHTML.indexOf("span") != -1){ var text = $(this).closest('td').find('span').text();` will never work as you might think. `this` refers to the `td` element, so `$(this).closest('td')` will simply return the element itself. Your code means: "If the cell does not contain a `span` element, find the `span` element inside of it". Doesn't make a lot of sense, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` and `.text()` instead of `.innerHTML` ( *as you are using jquery* )

**Change**

```
$('td', tr).each(function(j, td) {
        if(td.innerHTML.indexOf("span") != -1){
            var text = $(this).closest('td').find('span').text();
            myTr.push($.trim(text));
        }
        else{
            myTr.push($.trim(td.innerHTML));
        }
    });
```

**To**

```
$('td').each(function() {
       myTr.push( $(this).text() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d8W9Q/

Comment: thanks.....do you have any suggestion for this question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995155/changing-html-table-columns-based-on-visibility-jquery

Comment: yes, use `<div>` grid layouts -maybe look into jquery ui - `sortable` too if you don't want to find a solution unique to you.

Comment: but i need to move columns depends upon the user input, not by dragging....say there are three columns visible and the user wants the last column to come first and first column to go last....for that we using up and down model....

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help @usernid I have never heard of an 'up down model'. Hope you find your answer.

Comment: say if i'm using http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/mateagar/fieldChooser/blob/master/demo/index.html for selection of columns to be displayed, when i submit after selection, based upon the selection order i want to display the column in my table.....is that possible

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery's .text() method, look at the reference here:

http://api.jquery.com/text/